# How can I design pages with this structure?

Tags: html, documentation

I have had a great doubt for a long time, and I have been able to observe in some manufacturers that chips and tutorials, such as espressif or microchip technology, use pages with this format in some of their tutorials:

[image]

I would like to know if this page format is some standard or is it just a popular template that is often used or generated with some framework?

It would be interesting to be able to implement some identical format, I hope you can help me.

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/328193)  You are encouraged to make an attempt.  If during your attempt you encounter a specific problem, such as a specific operation producing an error or an unexpected result, we can help with that.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is made using a document generator, and there are lots of them out there.

The specific one in your image example seem to be [Read the docs](https://readthedocs.org/).

You can look up "documentation generator" or "static documentation generator" for more examples.